# Private relay working together with Mullvad

Tags: icloud, vpn

Most of the time I have iCloud Private Relay enabled. Occasionally I use Mullvad VPN. Recently, I do not know exactly when, this combination stopped working.

After installation of Mullvad VPN, iCloud Private Relay is not working anymore. I get this pop-up stating

> **Private Relay Unavailable** Your system settings are incompatible with Private Relay.

[image: macOS notification stating Private Relay Unavailable]

Uninstalling Mullvad VPN and rebooting brings Private Relay back to life. But I still want to use Mullvad VPN now and then. So that's not a permanent solution.

I tried to manually disable all Mullvad components. To do this, I ranthe first part of the [Mullvad uninstall script](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app/blob/master/dist-assets/uninstall_macos.sh), see below. After running this script and turning private relay off and on I still get the same error.

```
echo "Stopping GUI process ..."
sudo pkill -x "Mullvad VPN" || echo "No GUI process found"

echo "Stopping and unloading mullvad-daemon system daemon ..."
DAEMON_PLIST_PATH="/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.mullvad.daemon.plist"
sudo launchctl unload -w "$DAEMON_PLIST_PATH"
sudo rm -f "$DAEMON_PLIST_PATH"

sudo dscl . -delete /groups/mullvad-exclusion || echo "Failed to remove 'mullvad-exclusion' group"


echo "Resetting firewall"
sudo /Applications/Mullvad\ VPN.app/Contents/Resources/mullvad-setup reset-firewall || echo "Failed to reset firewall"
sudo /Applications/Mullvad\ VPN.app/Contents/Resources/mullvad-setup remove-device || echo "Failed to remove device from account"
```

On further investigation I found the following issue [Mullvad-daemon (without VPN active) on macOS Ventura disrupts iCloud Private Relay #4215](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app/issues/421). On the Mullvad GitHub. So it's a common problem.

What I am know looking for is a workaround. Is it possible to temporarily disable Mullvad and enable Private Relay again, without uninstall and reboot?

This issue exists with Mullvad VPN `2022.05` on both `macOS 13.1` and `13.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Mullvad released version [2023.1](https://github.com/mullvad/mullvadvpn-app/releases/tag/2023.1) a few days ago (2/20/2023). While I haven't tried it yet, it may be worth testing the new version to see if the issue has been resolved. If the problem persists, consider using Wireguard instead.

Here is a link to the instructions for installing Wireguard on a Mac. - [Link](https://mullvad.net/en/help/wireguard-macos-app/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still occurs with Mullvad Client 2023.1. I will consider trying Wireguard instead.